# Node SOAP request successful but unable to expose object

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I am having an issue exposing SOAP results from the [Node.js SOAP module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap).

The following code successfully makes an authenticated soup request.

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://example.com/soap.php?wsdl';
var args = {SecurityToken: '123abc456def789'};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  client.GetAllMarketAreas(args, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

But the console.log returns the following:

```
{ GetAllMarketAreasResult: { ROOT: { METHODINFO: [Object], DATA: [Object] } } }
```

I am assuming that the data is being sent back, I'm just not able to view it through the reference in the console.log. Does this sound correct and if so, how would I expose the date through Node's parsing?

The SOAP response looks like the following if done through SoupUI:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.eventinventory.com/webservices/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:GetAllMarketAreasResponse>
     <ns1:GetAllMarketAreasResult>
        <ROOT>
           <METHODINFO>
              <channelName>Basic View</channelName>
              <methodName>GetAllMarketAreas</methodName>
              <parameters>SecurityToken=123abc456def789</parameters>
              <processTime type="milliseconds">20.8221</processTime>
           </METHODINFO>
           <DATA xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql">
              <row ID="0" Name="International/Unknown"/>
              <row ID="1" Name="Calgary, AB"/>
              <row ID="4" Name="Abilene, TX"/>
              <row ID="6" Name="Aguadilla, PR"/>
              <row ID="7" Name="Boston, MA"/>
              ...
```

So my end goal is to view that data through a JSON object in Node JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in util library's [inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) method to introspect those objects.

```
var util = require('util')

...

console.log(util.inspect(result))
```

You can mess with depth, colors, etc via the interface to the command.